# How to activate c++11 support on MinGW using CMake?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, mingw

I've installed latest version of MinGW/MSYS environment. Now I try to activat c++11 standard support. I've added to my cmake script:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
```

If I try to build a simple test. I got the following compile failure:

```
error: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'
```

It seems to me that c++11 support is not set. If I remove the std::shared_ptr declaration from my code and try to compile some code of the chrono library it works. This confuses me.
Why some c++11 libraries are supported but core elements like shared_ptr fails?

Do I need to do something extra to enable smart pointers or they are just not there?

Comment: What compiler do you use exactly?

Comment: Did you `#include <memory>`?

Comment: Include the version number in the question. "Latest" won't be accurate for long.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the memory include. This was misleadingly out commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/should (also) use `-std=c++0x` so as to not enable g++ extension.

Make sure to `#include <memory>`.